# Can I playback a SVG animation within SMIL?

Tags: html, svg, smil

for a digital signage project, I created a SVG based rundown, which plays other SVG files in a loop on a Spinetix box.

Now I had to change the playback device. The new one supports SMIL and I'm looking for a way to reuse my old solution on this device. I think of creating a SMIL rundown which plays the standalone SVG files (basically it's the same, I think).

I googled and searched and didn't find a way to realize this. Any ideas? I appreciate your help on this one.

Thank you,
Juri

Answer (score 1):

SMIL is less powerful then SVG as it only handles the playlist timings.. Therefore it will be dificult for you to have the SVG projects taken over on a SMIL-only device ...

SpinetiX launches apparently a new software which is running inside their players, according to the video's it's realy simple to update content now ...

james

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot mark your answer as accepted as it doesn't help me directly with my problem, but be assured that I highly appreciate it. I was under the impression that I could playback a SVG file as part of a SMIL rundown just like any picture or video. One of the reasons we partially moved away from Spinetix is their high price point, but the HMP200 has a promising feature set.